# Detecting width of pattern using deep-learning

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning

I have a defined pattern. and image is divided into fixed size of squares. every square is filled with this pattern i want to implement a machine learning algorithm that can check if this pattern width match the size i gave or not. the values that width can take is very small.

Comment: You described what you want to do, but you don’t say what your problem with solving that task is.

Comment: I dont know what approach i can use , i tried using cnn of different filter size it gives me a bad accuracy.

Comment: Which approaches have you tried? Bounding box detection algorithms could be an option for you if I get the question correctly.